# import data from multiple file and summing column wise

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have n number of txt files each having 99  floating numbers in 99 column. I read each files and append all data by following script.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
msd_files = (glob.glob('MSD_no_fs*'))
msd_all=[]

for msd_file in msd_files:
    # print(msd_file)
    msd = numpy.loadtxt(fname=msd_file, delimiter=',')
    msd_all.append(msd)
```

After that I need to make column wise summation of each files. for example file1,column1+file2,column1+...+file(n)column(1) and iterate this for all column. What will be the effective way to perform this? Can I use list comprehension for that?
**edited code and it works fine now.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

msd_files = (glob.glob('MSD_no_fs*'))
msd_all=[]

for msd_file in msd_files:
    with open(msd_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            # msd_all.append([float(v) for v in line.strip().split(',')])
            msd_all.append(float(line.strip()))

msa_array = np.array(msd_all)
x=np.split(msa_array,99)
x=np.array(x)
result=np.mean(x,axis=0)
print(result.shape)
print(len(result))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on efficiency level you want. Using numpy to load many csv files might be a bad choice. Here is my suggestion.

```
import glob
import numpy as np

msd_files = (glob.glob('MSD_no_fs*'))
msd_all=[]

for msd_file in msd_files:
    with open(msd_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            msd_all.append([float(v) for v in line.strip().split(',')])

msa_array = np.array(msd_all)
result = msa_array.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: but what about the column wise addition? is that the sum will taking care of the addition according to the argument axis=0?

Comment: If what you want to do is adding values in each column across multiple files, `.sum(axis=0)` should work. The code will give 99 values.

Comment: @kilm your code did not give me the exact result but it helps me to sort out my problem.  I have edited my answer with full solution. Thanks. I am acceepting your answer as it helps me. Can you please vote for me question as i do not have any vote it gets difficult to post questions.